# Definition of an E-infinity algebra

Tags: homotopy-theory, homological-algebra, stable-homotopy-category

Can anyone give me a plain-and-simple
definition of an E-infinity algebra without using
the words "operad," "ring spectrum," or
"stable homotopy"?

Sorry, but I honestly couldn't find it using
all on-line resources at my disposal.

Thanks!

Comment: This can be done without the second two phrases, but trying to define it without the concept of an operad might be very difficult.

Comment: In characteristic zero, you can obtain an equivalent category to E-infinity algebras by taking commutative differential graded algebras (unbounded) and inverting the quasi-isomorphisms. Then you have commutativity on the nose, and don't have to worry about all the higher stuff. It's of course a cheat, but it's without operads, ring spectra and stable homotopy theory. 

Comment: A-infinity algebras have a straightforward definition that a computer can understand without having to be versed in loop spaces or homotopy theory (not that there's anything wrong with that).

Are you telling me that there is no definition written down for
E-infinity?  I find that implausible.

@Timo:  if you make the analogous statement for A-infinity algebras, it would still be true, but there would be Massey products nevertheless.

In short, I want a formula!     

    -Thanks

Comment: If you want a formula, then perhaps you should look at the operad defined in the papers of McClure-Smith http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0106024 and Berger-Fresse http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0109158 .  Of course, these involve the word "operad", but they give quite explicit example(s) of a chain-level E-infinity operad.

Comment: Like Eric, I'd be very curious to see formulae. If this is really not feasible, what about equations for a structure on singular cochains that governs stable (rather than unstable) homotopy theory? Mod $p$ stable homotopy theory?

Comment: (The last comment was written before seeing Charles Rezk's helpful response.)

Comment: 
Charles and Tim, shame on you both!  (Smily icon here.)
I understand that the algebraic structure is just some
superficial indication of a deeper structure, but I
do not want this question hijacked by you structuralists!

(Tim, where would symplectic geometry be if Fukaya hadn't
written down formulas?)

That said, I'm sure that there's a smart someone out
there who can turn Charles's references into a formula. 
(But I ain't him!)

Curmudgeonly yours,

Comment: Eric, quite so, and I'm sorry if I seemed to hijack the question. I've asked this question to algebraic topologists myself, and also been frustrated by the lack of concrete answers...

Comment: @Eric: Yes, there is a very short and powerful way to describe A-infinity algebras in terms of a very mild amount of chain-level data, which comes from one very nice A-infinity operad.  I guess I feel like the problem is the E-infinity operads, in terms of generators and relations, tend to be much larger and more difficult to work with on a practical basis; one needs infinitely many cup-i products at the very least before one has even left the binary operations.

Comment: @Tyler:  Okay, then is there a way of truncating your answer to the first non-trivial case?  For example, we can talk about an A_3 structure, which only involves the differential, the product, and the associator m_3.  I'd be happy with an E-analogue of that (I am not writing E_3, since I have been told that all of A-infinity is just E_1).  Is there no answer to the analogy:  m_3 is to A-infinity as ___ is to E-infinity?

Comment: @Eric: One of the problems is that the operations don't usually come in a natural sequence.  Does the operator producing commutativity come before associativity?  Does the pentagon axiom take place before the hexagon?  Should we take all the operators with only two inputs first?  (Clark Barwick has some thoughts on this, if he's paying attention.)  My suggestion is to take a look at operads and the references Charles mentioned - an operad is simply an object that parametrizes these operations that you're interested in, and that's what they try to describe.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In characteristic 0, Kadeishvili has a notion of $C_{\infty}$ algebra which models rational homotopy theory.  See the last paragraph of the introduction of his paper arXiv:0811.1655.  His point of view is to simply consider $A_{\infty}$ algebras whose operations satisfy a certain property with respect to shuffle maps.  So your computer doesn't have to remember any new operations, just check that the old ones are right.

In characteristic $p$, things are probably hopeless.

Added Remark:  I just want to make clear that this does not give a "trivial proof" that a commutative dga is formal as a commutative dga if the underlying dga is formal in the "non-commutative" sense.  The reason is that when you transfer from cochains from cohomology, you are restricted in the kind of morphisms allowed if you are interested in the commutative theory.  So, just as in the answers to this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9146/noncommutative-rational-homotopy-type), there is some work to be done if you want results like that (to be completely honest, there is not yet a proof that I completely understand, so declare myself agnostic).

Comment: 
Thanks, Mohammed.  This is a very simple definition.  The "certain property" above is just that the m_k vanish when you replace any d<k inputs by the signed sum of their d! permutations.  My computer thanks you, too!

Comment: @Eric. Beware, Eric, that Mohammed is talking about $C_\infty$ algebras: they are *not* the same as $E_\infty$ algebras. I think there is no simple description of $E_\infty$ algebras in terms of generators (operations) and relations like the ones avaliable for $A_\infty$ or $C_\infty$ ones. McClure-Smith's paper cited by Charles Rezk seems to provide the simplest one, but still is far more complicated than those for $A_\infty$ or $C_\infty$ cases.

Comment: Grrr!  Why doesn't life get simpler?  So then, how to understand Kadeishvili's comment, "In rational case E-infinity o-- can be replaced by commutative o-- C acting on appropriate cochains. And in order to step from cochains to cohomology we replace C be the o-- C-infinity," where "o--" is a forbidden word.

I gather that E-infinity involves the structure of permuting inputs, and that there are many higher products coming from ways of organizing said inputs.  This is intuitive, but also suggests that there is some algebraic simplification by capping the number of inputs at say 3.  Or, why not?

Comment: My understanding is that if one cares about quasi-isomorphism types of commutative dga's then the two theories ($E_\infty$ or $C_{\infty}$) give the same answer rationally.  It would be great if we had a comment from experts confirming or denying this.

Comment: not an expert, but here's something using one of the forbidden words.  Both $C_\infty$ and $E_\infty$ operads are cofibrant resolutions of the commutative operad, but $E_\infty$ has the added condition that $E_\infty(n)$ is contractible.  Working rationally, there are maps between $E_\infty$ and $C_\infty$ since they are resolutions of the same object. 

Comment: @Eric. If I remember correctly (with the help of Markl, Shnider, Stasheff, "Operads in Algebra...", page 19,  :-)    ), $C_\infty$ algebras are $A_\infty$ algebras which are *strictly* commutative. Whereas, of course, $E_\infty$ algebras are not.

Comment: @Agusti: this statement is not true. A $C_\infty$ algebra is a $A\infty$ algebra which vanishes on the image of non-trivial shuffles, not that they are "strictly symmetric".

Answer (score 28):

In characteristic 0, one can define an $E_\infty$-algebra simply by an $A_\infty$-algebra $(A, d, \lbrace \mu_n\rbrace_{n\ge 2})$ such that each operations $\mu_n$ vanishes on the sum of all $(p, q)$-shuffles for $p + q = n$.

[See Section 13.1.13 of http://math.unice.fr/~brunov/Operads.html for more details.]

Answer (score 25):

Drinfeld once remarked to me something to the effect
that he likes the definition of an operad because it
is so simple.  One doesn't have to be a Drinfeld to
appreciate the truth of that statement. It is the 
simplicity of the notion that led me to search for 
a name with a nice ring to it, that people would 
remember.  Steenrod operations were originally defined
using operads implicitly.  For odd primes, I believe 
there is still no ``simple'', by which I understand 
combinatorially explicit, construction of the operations.

Comment: Dear Professor May, is there still no way to do it even if one uses the simplicial approach of Hovey-Shipley-Smith to obtain a symmetric monoidal product of (symmetric) spectra?  From what I understand (perhaps quite wrongly!), is that their approach avoids any explicit mention of operads, although it does still depend on doing a variant of stable homotopy theory.

Comment: You are mixing contexts and definitions in a fairly confused way.
$E_{\infty}$ algebras make sense in many categories.  There are 
many symmetric monoidal categories of spectra (historically, the
first, by a nose, was constructed in EKMM (Elmendorf-Kriz-Mandell-May).  In any such category, commutative monoids, alias commutative 
ring spectra, are equivalent to $E_{\infty}$ algebras in the 
relevant category of spectra.

Answer (score 9):

A completely explicit definition that works over any ring is given as Proposition 18 in the following preprint of Malte Dehling and Bruno Vallette that was posted on the arXiv today. http://arxiv.org/abs/1503.02701

Comment: That's a very nice paper.