# An $E_{\infty}$-algebra is a $C_{\infty}$-algebra?

Tags: homotopy-theory, homological-algebra, higher-category-theory, stable-homotopy, higher-algebra

Past [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/36444/317253) in MO have raised the following questions for me.

**Question**

In characteristic $0$, it is well-known that a Kadeishvili‘s $C_{\infty}$-algebra is an $E_{\infty}$-algebra.

However, do we have an example of $E_{\infty}$-algebras which is not a $C_{\infty}$-algebra?
(We always only consider characteristic 0)

Any comment is welcome.
Thank you!

See also comments below.

Comment: Any $C_\infty$-algebra is weakly equivalent to a cdga, namely the cobar complex of its bar complex. For $E_\infty$-algebras, Dyer-Lashov operations are an obstruction to the existence of such a weak equivalence.

Comment: You should maybe clarify what you mean by $E_\infty$ and $C_\infty$. I’ve only seen the latter considered in characteristic zero, where both notions coincide for almost all possible definitions.

Comment: @FernandoMuro Thank you. I only consider characteristic 0 and the definitions of $C_{\infty} $ and $E_{\infty}$ algebras in Section 13.1.8~13.1.10 of Loday-Vallette's book.

Comment: @BertramArnold Thank you. "weakly equivalent" means quasi-isomorphic as $C_{\infty}$-algebras?

Comment: @Walterfield then you can find an answer to your question in the first paragraph of 13.1.10.

Comment: @FernandoMuro Thank you. You mean the answer is no because the operad $Com_\infty$ is an $E_\infty$-operad?

Comment: @Walterfield right the contrary.

Comment: @FernandoMuro I misunderstood. You mean that $Com_\infty$ is just one model of $E_\infty$-operad.
So it is possible to have an $E_\infty$-algebra that does not appear as an algebra over $Com_\infty$.

Comment: @Walterfield the consequence is the opposite of what you say. Both notions coincide.

Comment: $Com_{\infty}$ is a cofibrant operad, so we always have a lifting on any $E_{\infty}$-operad by $Com_{\infty}$ and any $E_{\infty}$-algebra is a $C_{\infty}$ algebra.