# Can we abelianize quasi-isomorphisms of dga?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra

Suppose that $A \leftarrow X_1 \to \dots \leftarrow X_m \to B$ is quiso of differential graded algebras, and $A, B$ happen to be (graded) commutative. Can we find *commutative* $Y_1, \dots, Y_n$ connecting $A$ and $B$? When this question came up to me, I thought at first "well, this should be obvious or, at least, proven 50 years ago", but then I failed to find any references or feasible arguments for or against.

Some musings on theme: suppose we have (connected to make things easier) cdga $C$. Consider its bar construction $BC$. If there exist a twisting cochain, that is, map $\epsilon: BC \otimes BC \to C$ with $[d, \epsilon] = \epsilon * \epsilon$, such that it has only degree one part ($\epsilon |_{BC \otimes BC^{\geq 2}} = 0$), then $C$ is commutative (I suppose that up to certain equivalence of twisting cochains it is also only if; not sure if I'm right). Maybe, we could try to emulate this argument using "bar construction of dga morphism".

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9146/noncommutative-rational-homotopy-type

Comment: I recommend having a look at D. Petersen's comment in that thread as it gives a reference to a solution in a special case.