# Reference for model structure on non-positively graded cdga's over a field of characteristic 0

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, model-categories

I was wondering if there were some references where the (projective?) model structure on $ cdga_k^{\leq 0}$, with $char(k) = 0$, and $deg(\partial) =1$ was explicitly described in detail, possibly including a discussion of semi-freeness?  Thanks!

Comment: Is your grading homological or cohomological (i.e., does the differential have degree 1 or −1)?

Comment: Some version of this question appeared previously: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5031/model-structure-of-commutative-dg-algebras-inside-all-dg-algebras